# How to associate a file extension to an electron app (multiplatform)

Tags: javascript, installation, electron, file-association, squirrel.windows

I already added the following snippet to my `package.json`:

```
"build": {
  "fileAssociations": [
    {
      "ext": "asdf",
      "name": "ASDF File",
      "role": "Editor"
    }
  ]
}
```

But the generated installer does not assign my application to the `asdf` extension. (tested on Windows 10)

I also looked up, how to edit the `setupEvents.js` file. It contains the following part:

```
case '--squirrel-updated':
 // Optionally do things such as:
 // - Add your .exe to the PATH
 // - Write to the registry for things like file associations and
 // explorer context menus
```

But I could not find a single example, how to archieve the registry writing part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the `"perMachine": true,` option, e.g.:

```
"build": {
  "fileAssociations": [
    {
      "ext": "asdf",
      "name": "ASDF File",
      "role": "Editor",
      "perMachine": true
    }
  ]
}
```

The reason it is needed, is because on Windows, per-user installed program cannot register file associations, and that is the default setting.

Comment: Works fine. Also, I had to use the .msi installer.

Comment: for anyone else, this config might also be in an external json file if using the --config flag

Answer (score 2):

It seems that with the newer version you need to set it like this

```
"build": {
   "fileAssociations": [{
     "ext": "ext1",
     "name": "ext1 File",
     "role": "Editor"
   },
   {
     "ext": "ext2",
     "name": "ext2File",
     "role": "Editor"
   }
   ],
   "nsis": {
     //othersettings,
     "perMachine": true
   }
}
```

there is more information about other file association settings [here](https://www.electron.build/generated/platformspecificbuildoptions)